# Unable to build a 'Enter y to loop' program

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I'm still learning the basics of C right now and I wanted to build a simple 'enter y to loop the program' that I've seen in a lot of console programs and wrote the following code to test it out. When I do execute it however, it does work as intended once after which the program just exits. It would help me a lot if anyone told me what I'm doing wrong here :

```
int main()
{
char l;
    do
    {
        printf("Loop successful.\n");
        fflush(stdin);  //I heard this has to be used because scanf keeps the enter key in buffer or something like that
        scanf_s("%c", &l);
    } while (l == 'y');
}
```

I also get a "Missing integer argument to 'scanf(_s)' that corresponds to conversion specifier '2'" warning and I don't seem to understand what I'm being warned against.

Comment: A little advice; naming a variable `l` is (a) uninformative, and (b) can be mistaken for a `1`, depending on font; I had to do a double-take on `while (1 == 'y')`...

Answer (score 2):

```
fflush(stdin);  //I heard this has to be used because scanf keeps the enter key in
```

That's wrong, `fflush`ing `stdin` is undefined behaviour, what you need to do is consume the newlines lefted by the previous scan, just switch from

```
    scanf_s("%c", &l);
```

to

```
    scanf_s(" %c", &l); // Notice the space before %
```

Comment: (.... with the note that there is one non-conforming OS that does define `fflush(stdin)` contrary to what is stated in the C-standard.. Cough... Microsoft...)

Comment: This does fix the issue, but how does adding a space fix this? I never put a space when I was working with %d for example.

Comment: Because `"%c"` and `"%[...]"` do NOT ignore leading whitespace. So adding a whitespace to the format string tells `scanf()` to ignore all whitespace in that position. `'\n'` is whitespace... (which is also why new C programmers are urged to use `fgets()` for all user input and the use `sscanf()` to parse values from the input...)